# Document custom annotation in spring rest docs

Tags: spring-restdocs

I have to integrate spring rest docs in a legacy project were they use a bunch of custom annotation (such as for example the user roles).
Is there a way in spring rest docs to document this annotation?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what the annotation does? REST Docs works at the level of HTTP requests and responses. Documenting the annotation will depend on the effect it has on those requests and responses.

Comment: i know how it works and i don't agree with the approach choose by my company. Basically what they want is to document a custom annotation similar to the @PreAuthorize one of spring security. There is annotation that determine the role a user must have to access a specific endpoint. Is there a way do document such thing?

Answer (score 1):

Spring REST Docs works at the level of HTTP requests and responses. By design, it doesn't know anything about annotations or how those requests are handled and the responses created. This ensures that what you're documenting is at the same level as a client interacting with your service over HTTP.

If you want to include information about `@PreAuthorize` or an annotation that is similar to it, you will have to write something yourself to do that. If you want to fit into the REST Docs way of doing things, you could implement a custom `Snippet` that's configured with a class or method from which it extracts the annotation using reflection and generates some documentation from it.

Comment: This is how i implemented that. But at the moment i have to configure my test to know witch class and method i'm testing. Do you know if there is a way to extract that in a Snippet class?